# Unable to register trigger for S3 bucket (global) to lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have my **lambda function deployed across region** (us-east-1 and us-west-2). I wish to register trigger from S3 for this lambda functions. And my **S3 bucket is global (not tied to specific region)**

I could only register trigger from us-east-1's lambda function but with it gives error while creating trigger from us-west-2 region.

> Your bucket must be in the same region as the function.

The same is also documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-prepare.html) (section 1.2)

> Both the source bucket and your Lambda function must be in the same
>   AWS region.

I think trigger should be possible when s3 bucket is global. Please correct my understanding if its wrong? If this is possible then please help me in correcting lambda/role configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Global defaults to us-east-1 region and that's the reason it works for lambda in us-east-1

Fanout S3 buckets to send notifications to an SNS (in us-east-1 region) and subscribe your lambdas in both regions to that SNS in us-east-1

This will help solve the issue.

Comment: This is correct.  There is no such thing as a global bucket.  A bucket without a location constraint is constrained to us-east-1.

Comment: Thanks for info. If both lambdas are subscribed for SNS topic, both lambdas will invoked or one of the lambda function?

Comment: both will be invoked by the SNS.

Comment: Is there any way to invoke only one of the lambda function?

Comment: Do not subscribe SNS to the lambda function which you do not want to be invoked. If for testing purposes, subscribe SNS but disable the SNS trigger in lambda